# how to become a salesforce.com partner

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, isv, partner-portal

I want to publish my app on appexchange so i have signup for partner portal. I log in using the partner portal dev org to appexchange and linked one of my org having my managed package. When i click start review i am getting error message as 
Please correct the following error(s):

```
To security review your application, you must be a salesforce.com partner and connect your partnership information to your provider profile. To connect this information, edit your provider profile.
```

so tell me how to complete my partnership with salesforce.com.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations for your new application. 
 You will get all the information regarding the partner program here: https://partners.salesforce.com/ 
 As far as I know, SFDC will ask you details about your application. Then one of the SFDC rep is assigned to you who will communicate with you regarding your partnership. 
 Cheers!
Shailesh

Comment: Shailesh can you tell me what are the steps to complete my partnership with salesforce.com.

Comment: Press the join now button on that page.